# How to display automatic 2 digits the last phone number to second textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to display 2 digits the last phone number when I input phone number to first text field and display automatic to second text field with AJAX or JavaScript or jQuery ?.

I want to get script about that for my website like [this video](https://youtu.be/bWLZ-CiQoZg?t=2m23s).

I've searched everywhere in Google Search about that, I only found [this JavaScript](http://jsbin.com/oleto5/5/edit?html,js,output).

But that is not solution. Please help me to resolve solution and what should I do.

Where I can get AJAX or JavaScript or jQuery like that or are there soluton in this forum ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you found, changing

```
$('#output').text($('#txt').val());
```

to

```
$('#output').text($('#txt').val().substr(-2));
```

would be what you need

or

```
$('#output').value($('#txt').val().substr(-2));
```

if the `output` is an `<input type="text" >` element

Comment: Ok, that is good. But how to display it in second textfield like in video ?. If I put input id="output" type="text", there is no result from first textfield for second textfield.

Answer (score -3):

I've combined this script from http://jsbin.com/oleto5/5/edit?html,js,output and http://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/tABDr/

But there is a little problem in code : `$('#numbers').val($('#tt').val()+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));`

If I remove `+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));` and script be replaced to `.substr(-2));` does not work.

If I use `+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));` is not perfect when I remove digits.

Example :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>berkelilingkesemua.info</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="jsbin" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" class="jsbin"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" class="jsbin"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $('#txt').keydown(function(){
 setTimeout(function() {
 $('#output').text($('#txt').val().substr(-2));
 }, 50);
});
});
</script>
<input id="txt" type="text" />
<div id="output"></div>

<hr>
Second script is combined by me from first script becomes like below.
<hr />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tt").keydown(function (event) {
 setTimeout(function() {
 }, 50);
 {
 $('#numbers').val($('#tt').val()+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
 }
});
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="tt" />
<input type="text" id="numbers" />

</body>
</html>
```

Are there solution about this script ?.