# How to fix display automatic 2 digits the last phone number to second textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've combined this script from http://jsbin.com/oleto5/5/edit?html,js,output and http://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/tABDr/

But there is a little problem in code : `$('#numbers').val($('#tt').val()+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));`

If I remove `+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));` and script be replaced to `.substr(-2));` does not work.

If I use `+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));` is not perfect when I remove digits.

Example :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>berkelilingkesemua.info</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="jsbin" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" class="jsbin"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" class="jsbin"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $('#txt').keydown(function(){
 setTimeout(function() {
 $('#output').text($('#txt').val().substr(-2));
 }, 50);
});
});
</script>
<input id="txt" type="text" />
<div id="output"></div>

<hr>
Second script is combined by me from first script becomes like below.
<hr />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tt").keydown(function (event) {
 setTimeout(function() {
 }, 50);
 {
 $('#numbers').val($('#tt').val()+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
 }
});
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="tt" />
<input type="text" id="numbers" />

</body>
</html>
```

Are there solution about this script ?.

Comment: Not quite clear as to what you're after.

Comment: I have made thread in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634224/how-to-display-automatic-2-digits-the-last-phone-number-to-second-textfield and I have explained like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWLZ-CiQoZg&feature=youtu.be&t=2m23s. But there is no more answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze it:
1. You're using HTML5, so why not to use the "input" event? It's more reliable then a "keyup"
2. To speed things up, always try to store a DOM element in a variable, so you won't have to navigate trough all the DOM tree every time, you press a button
3. Use slice() method, to get a proper string.

```js
var source = $("#tt"),
    target = $("#numbers");
source.on('input', function() {
  target.val(source.val().slice(-2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tt" />
<input type="text" id="numbers" />
```

Comment: This script works in this forum when run code snippet, but not works in my Browser.

Comment: Possibly because you have to add the event listener somewhere. Try to wrap it with on document ready event: `$(function() {
    // code from answer;
});`

Comment: Ok, script is working. I forget put code `$(document).ready(function() {` in the first code and I also put code `});` in the last code. Thank you. I have found the answer from you like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWLZ-CiQoZg&feature=youtu.be&t=2m23s

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after one of the following.

```
$('#output').text( $(this).val().slice(0, -2) );

$('#output').text( $(this).val().slice(-2) );
```

A demo using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
$(function() {
    $('#txt').keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('#output1').val( $this.val().slice(0, -2) ); //Grab everything but the last 2 characters.
        $('#output2').val( $this.val().slice(-2) ); //Grab the last 2 characters.
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="output1"></span><br/>
<input type="text" id="output2"></span>
```

Comment: No, I mean like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWLZ-CiQoZg&feature=youtu.be&t=2m23s

Comment: Thank you lshettyl.  I have found the answer from eeree in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635465/how-to-fix-display-automatic-2-digits-the-last-phone-number-to-second-textfield/31635579#31635579 and I save your answer and your code. Maybe I also need your code. Nice to meet you lshettyl.